# Create a one month calendar with events on it in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, calendar

I want to create a one month calendar that I can print out and hand to normal people that has events already on it.

I want to do something similar to what [WinCalendar](http://www.wincalendar.com/Create-a-Calendar-from-Excel-Data) does.  I would use that program, but the reviews mention sketchy DLLs, registry keys, and startup defaults.  Shouldn't there be a python library that does this?

Here's the [github](https://github.com/meta4/mplcal) link for the project and files below.

I can create what I want using matplotlib as follows.

```
import calendar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

calendar.setfirstweekday(6) # Sunday is 1st day in US
w_days = 'Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat'.split()
m_names = '''
January February March April
May June July August
September October November December'''.split()

class MplCalendar(object):
    def __init__(self, year, month):
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.cal = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)
        # monthcalendar creates a list of lists for each week
        # Save the events data in the same format
        self.events = [[[] for day in week] for week in self.cal]
        
    def _monthday_to_index(self, day):
        'The index of the day in the list of lists'
        for week_n, week in enumerate(self.cal):
            try:
                i = week.index(day)
                return week_n, i
            except ValueError:
                pass
         # couldn't find the day
        raise ValueError("There aren't {} days in the month".format(day))

    def add_event(self, day, event_str):
        'insert a string into the events list for the specified day'
        week, w_day = self._monthday_to_index(day)
        self.events[week][w_day].append(event_str)

    def show(self):
        'create the calendar'
        f, axs = plt.subplots(len(self.cal), 7, sharex=True, sharey=True)
        for week, ax_row in enumerate(axs):
            for week_day, ax in enumerate(ax_row):
                ax.set_xticks([])
                ax.set_yticks([])
                if self.cal[week][week_day] != 0:
                    ax.text(.02, .98,
                            str(self.cal[week][week_day]),
                            verticalalignment='top',
                            horizontalalignment='left')
                contents = "\n".join(self.events[week][week_day])
                ax.text(.03, .85, contents,
                        verticalalignment='top',
                        horizontalalignment='left',
                        fontsize=9)

        # use the titles of the first row as the weekdays
        for n, day in enumerate(w_days):
            axs[0][n].set_title(day)

        # Place subplots in a close grid
        f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
        f.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
        f.suptitle(m_names[self.month] + ' ' + str(self.year),
                   fontsize=20, fontweight='bold')
        plt.show()
```

Then I can create a MplCalendar object, add events and display it as follows.

```
from matplotlib_calendar import MplCalendar
import matplotlib_calendar

feb = MplCalendar(2017, 2) #2017, February
feb.add_event(1, '1st day of February')
feb.add_event(5, '         1         2         3         4         5         6')
feb.add_event(5, '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890')
feb.add_event(18, 'OSLL Field Maintenance Day')
feb.add_event(18, 'OSLL Umpire Mechanics Clinic')
feb.add_event(20, 'Presidents day')
feb.add_event(25, 'OSLL Opening Day')
feb.add_event(28, 'T-Ball Angels vs Dirtbags at OSLL')
feb.show()
```

This produces a calendar that looks like this.

[image: Sample February Matplotlib Calendar]

Am I reinventing a wheel here?  I have tried a bunch of related Google searches and I can't find anything.

Comment: Hi, looks nice, did you find anything else?

Comment: I never did.  

I still use it a couple of times a year.  I could turn it into a pip installable package.  Do you think that would be useful?

Comment: Did not try it yet, before you add it to pip, put it in GitHub :)

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has answered this and it has almost 5k views I thought there should be something for a 6 year old question.  So, the question was

> Am I reinventing a wheel here?

While the question can illicit opinionated answers in general, this question is really only important in production situations.  In OPs situation the project is personal and made available to the public for those that are interested.  Even if, 6 years ago, there were other event calendars in python, recreating their solution lets you learn or practice the thought process involved in structuring the solution.  While the code itself might not teach you anything new about the language, it can still be a worthwhile mental exercise to do.

in short, 6 years ago, no you probably weren't re-inventing even though you were solving a problem that had a solution you wanted to use a different route to get there.

In general, I'm not a fan of the term 're-inventing the wheel' as the wheel itself gets reinvented all the time, there's no other way we would have run flats if not.  There's always something to learn, if it's not about code or the language then it's about the thought process of how a problem was broken down, solved and the syntax choices (why wasn't inheritance used, why was 1 algo picked over another... ect).